# Replace Return charcter to &#xD

Tags: xml, bash, sed, fedora, pki

I have pkcs10 request in a file, which i need to convert the new line character in the file to ""

Example:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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```

-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

I would like to change the above to below format:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----&#xD;
MIIC2zCCAcMCAQAwcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEDAOBgNVBAoTB1JlZCBIYXQxDjAM&#xD;
BgNVBAsTBVFFSURNMQswCQYDVQQLEwJRRTENMAsGA1UECxMEUkhTUzEVMBMGCgmS&#xD;
JomT8ixkAQETBXRlc3Q2MQ4wDAYDVQQDEwV0ZXN0NjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB&#xD;
BQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALu2ootYtjVwwmTSDh2mQxbgWGOgMLEHlvzbG6Xzdqc0&#xD;
c8mQkm8jZvB4JE5TiXmNj4YWnnJNehKCqog3xUwpNo6P1uW5l0p1D2Dk9n/pCuvW&#xD;
zQ237mWBB6tYoHYiqyFgcip7ptbytQjykhx+1UbqgnACVW2FHaVLcGSyfMRoaOZS&#xD;
LjxZUui4aFDe9pS9nv0Dk+34/xJS2y/UjKTFMziieQzmBT63Yk+1NMmlGIrVl+en&#xD;
hvh6bctMdpeaTkDy327+y/BeQzR3qoUK4RcOB6vq1u40PkKwwy/lGF2mCNwIQnBY&#xD;
ExZsr6nuC1kMgRG7776scMztO4rtoUtkazjxIJc5K3MCAwEAAaAkMCIGCCsGAQUF&#xD;
BwcXMRYEFOZpyV8u/6SQrnPmRMw/nh2Wd5xQMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQA7&#xD;
L0p4N4/94u4d4RgYoPuBVH09J12CXh/NtKUsiiTRC41IaVggSoe3L3bR20DhELtZ&#xD;
IIbtrijktg9eNkUHfIQmZu9GjIs9GtKQMQx7YbOC9xHq7kWffxbUyTgQ6pFQyoGE&#xD;
toGME2wP6MPhEkUNiIYNam8Tt+qUiz6t5j3MGB8HwoF+qNpEfo8tNtfgonpOnYns&#xD;
i2SUbc1Y1Nj15IZfkMXRdaRj+a0HxLR7kDVayRYxO5H4cHuCG9N0vLkNtkdwPboI&#xD;
TyoNsrSqgZVP2U7B82qfo8YcSTG2D/B8KHnSbMIYCl1e3u//b6zcC1NODpffOYCF&#xD;
xVxiFitfbtweWcWipxWS&#xD;
&#xD;
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST----
```

Any tools like xed or xml tools on Linux that could achieve the above.

Comment: *"I would like to change the above to below format"* - You most certainly do not want that. Would you care to explain why you think that's necessary?

Comment: I have to generate a pkcs10 request and provide the request in an xml format because the pki server that i am using accpets the request be put in an xml file

Comment: Any specific reason why you feel that changing could have issue ?

Comment: Yes. First you seem to be using text tools to generate XML. This is wrong, you really should use an XML API. They are abundant in any programming environment, there is no excuse for using `sed`. Second, XML is perfectly capable of retaining line breaks. You absolutely don't need to do anything special, adding `&#xD;` to your text is plain wrong. Just use - for example - Python with `etree` to build the XML you need, store the key string in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\&#xD;&/g' filename
```

For saving the changes to the input file in-place, add the `-i` option.

For your input, this would produce:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----&#xD;
MIIC2zCCAcMCAQAwcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEDAOBgNVBAoTB1JlZCBIYXQxDjAM&#xD;
BgNVBAsTBVFFSURNMQswCQYDVQQLEwJRRTENMAsGA1UECxMEUkhTUzEVMBMGCgmS&#xD;
JomT8ixkAQETBXRlc3Q2MQ4wDAYDVQQDEwV0ZXN0NjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB&#xD;
BQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALQULllI/JMudcBHeykXe7wRmAZlcxxQK7pvw1hNqt/I&#xD;
Lz4XdZJ9pZVHCSmeR3ubsriRbbqhM2ZjiH+Rb2mLxCgrVlqvBEZ5qj6yQhhiWaFL&#xD;
wNIGFhGHqFt/HeDxDvuLumZVH34VDGZoIoPLVMtVspHG5kxKHEsivWMvkkUnrbJF&#xD;
X8Bdsfhzg/7pObkZtaUrg9tjXRCU+hrPnodfUgZ8IxzWcaaKFs7c4f6QjFOsDCQz&#xD;
8TxuiF5gDbWbXlpVRnEtofpMZrtnxYe92Sepi83kduZ9aWyZMFNND8HWl9zpjwy3&#xD;
uFUrs+R+S8zRM3tww92CuCgsaA+fjftlFKnIXaAl7dkCAwEAAaAkMCIGCCsGAQUF&#xD;
BwcXMRYEFOZpyV8u/6SQrnPmRMw/nh2Wd5xQMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQCm&#xD;
djxD+5NJqFIKKWaVEq3QNDwqNiD/j+bi7EyDPquwBfgpp1VZmOty99muStG2GfvE&#xD;
1tg7ZdcebDHZ5umIw//3StxTODVkUYIkYzWERdt3GZe3TJqdGDeWMkOtCQR0fMjs&#xD;
X1TN0m1BEKS1tKoMJWJagCLvsqr2C+LMw4gB/r/Tq+KUvacM+yv7x0ROgRKa6aiW&#xD;
/ja2vox3uWUMUMKYbz8km5UrqnaSBVDvDIt8yt9X5k+2sgl37MsWzyKBnpwH7mKX&#xD;
5Z8vj9C8F3Iq0L6qWQdqCY74nm/jyI4roUQpDoS+xeQxKh6mn8IbX2HisGwSoJyM&#xD;
w8jfHjDvXxRi0RyBlBNR&#xD;
&#xD;
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '$ !s/$/\&#xD;/' YourFile
```

or

```
sed '$ !s/[[:blank:]]*$/\&#xD;/' YourFile
```

is not enough ?